# How to add a point inside a matplotlib contour plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to draw a phase portrait of a system of ordinary differential equations in a 2D phase space, and used the `streamplot` function of matplotlib to achieve it. And I would like to mark some points (the fixed points) in the figure, but I don't know how to do it on the same diagram, for using `scatter` only plots points on another figure. How can I do it? The following is what I have for now:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""
The system of ODE is given by:
dx/dt = alpha*(1-x)*x - c*x*y
dy/dt = -b*y + d*x*y
"""

# Set the parameters
alpha, b, c, d = 4, 3, 2, 1

# The fixed points
fp = [(0, 0), (1,0), (b/d, alpha/c*(1-b/d))]

# The phase portrait lies in {(x,y)|-l<x<l, -l<y<l} with n arrows in each dimension
l, n = 2, 41

# The 'velocity' of a point in phase space = (dx/dt, dy/dt)
def velocity(x, y):
    return alpha*(1-x)*x - c*x*y, -b*y + d*x*y

# Mesh the grids in x-y space
x, y = np.linspace(-l, l, n), np.linspace(-1, 1, n)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
U, V = velocity(X, Y)
plt.figure()
plt.streamplot(X, Y, U, V)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you add `plt.scatter(..)` somewhere in between `plt.figure()` and `plt.show()` it'll plot to the same plot.